# Moderator ping doesn't work for the Community Building site after the rename

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, moderator-tools

`whois` in TL is borken!

> [image: borken whois 1]

Later...

> [image: borken whois 2]

Eeek!

*for ♦s: here's [the conversation in TL](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/conversation/were-all-gonna-die).*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Fixed now](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18875637#18875637). All that was needed was a refresh of AJ's user data. This would've happened automatically the next time he comes to chat (or by itself, eventually -- normal users are refreshed once per hour *if they are in chat*; moderators are also force-refreshed every 2-3 days).

The "refresh profile from parent site" button on the user profile (accessible to moderators) does the same thing, and thus would have fixed it as well (and pushing that button is exactly what I did).

Comment: I upvote you for pushing the right buttons

Comment: I'm not sure I want to be "fixed".  I've only had one kid so far.  And ironically, I actually knew the answer to this one, but somehow didn't discover it until someone else mentioned the meta post to me.

Comment: Don't worry @AJHenderson, *you* haven't been fixed. But you've been refreshed!